# Python sqlite3 - Read Only From Multiple Threads = SLOW

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I have a simple Python class that subclasses from Thread.  In the run method, I connect to sqlite db, make a simple select query, and close the connection.  Pretty standard stuff:

```
def run(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(SHAPE_CACHE_DB)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute('SELECT * from foo')
    for row in curs.fetchall():
       # do stuff
    curs.close()
    conn.close()
```

When only one thread is run at a time, the run method executes very fast - lets just < 1 second.  But if multiple instances of the class are instantiated and run - lets say 6 or more, the run method can take many seconds???

I am guessing there is some contention between read access amongst the threads.  But I thought sqlite allowed read access to concurrent threads???

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the sqlite module isn't threadsafe:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#multithreading

Secondly, you are doing the "SAME" query from six threads that means you are doing six times as much the work. A somewhat fairer comparison would be if your single threaded version was doing six queries in a loop.

Thirdly, for you will have thread switching with multiple threads and pay some cost for that.

Comment: The sql does actually change per thread.  And in the python doc link you reference, it says cursors and connections cant be shared across threads.  I am not doing that here - each thread manages its own connection and cursor.  So some other lock must be in play here.

Comment: although sql does change between threads - result set size will be very close.

Comment: Agreed, the first reason doesn't apply to speed anyway. It was just an FYI. If the resultset size will be very similar then that may be the reason for the larger time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is/was a GIL issue.  Rather than subclass Thread, I switched to multiprocessing.Process - all instances of the class now perform similarly.